# How to move in next tab on text click in React Native using TabView?

Tags: react-native, navigation, tabview

I am new in React Native. I am using TabView [react-native-tab-view - npm] in my project. I declared one const for rendering screens like :

```
const renderScene = SceneMap({
      signin: Sign_in,
       signup: Sign_up,
  });
```

and when on text click i want to jump next tab and write code like below :

```
<Text style={style.signup_text} onPress={() => { this.props.jumpTo('signup') }}>Sing Up</Text>
```

Its working fine but when i change my code to pass navigation property to that tab's class than its not working .Code is like:

```
const renderScene = SceneMap({
        signin: () => <Sign_in navigation={navigation} />,
        signup: () => <Sign_up navigation={navigation}  />,
    });
```

Now how can i move to next tab .Using above code jumpTo is not working. I hope you will understand what i want to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to send custom props to components you have to chage the renderScene to

```
const renderScene = (props) => {
    switch (props.route.key) {
      case 'signin':
        return <Sign_in {...props} {...{navigation}} />;
      case 'signup':
        return <Sign_un {...props} {...{navigation}}/>;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ref of TabView, after use jumpToIndex(index)

```
const [tabView, setTabView] = useState(null);

<TabView
navigationState={{ index, routes }}
renderScene={renderScene}
ref={(tabView) => {
    setTabView(tabView);
}}
renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
/>

<Button onPress={()=>{tabView.jumpToIndex(3);} />
```